# QGIS shutting down when trying to create a polygon

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon-creation

QGIS keeps shutting down when I try to create a polygon. It only happens with polygons, not with lines, and only when I try to create a new one, while it works fine if I try to modify the nodes of an existing polygon. I have tried to download a more recent version (I have always used 3.10 so I tried with 3.28) but the issue remains. I have also tried to create a new shape file from scratch but as soon as I draw the polygon and click 'OK' it shuts down. I really don't understand why this is happening and how to fix it. I use MacOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Have you tried different file types? Have you tried using a different project? Have you tried using a temporary layer? Is snapping/tracing enabled? What are your settings when it comes to faulty geometries?

Comment: Hi, tried different files, tried different projects, tried different users. I have also just tried with a temporary layer: at first it seemed to work but then it shut down again. Snapping/tracing are not enabled but neither were before this problem started (it happened a few times in the past days, but now it is constant). Where do I check my settings for faulty geometries - bare with me am self taught and def not an expert.

Comment: Consider raising a bug report with the QGIS project: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html

Comment: First, try creating a new, clean profile. This useful blog explains the process: https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-profiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: It turned out this was nothing to do with QGIS! The culprit was my usb hub (not from Apple) which made my laptop crash - for some reason this only happened when creating polygons with QGIS. I realised it when in a final attempt I disconnected any peripheral devices. Since disconnecting the hub QGIS has been running smoothly.